# Looking for a View

Tags: android

Well, I'm going to make my first "important project" and I want to use a specific view, but I don't know the name of it.
It's a really used view, you can see it, for example in the McDonalds App, it's the first view you see, it's like a Scroll view, but the image inside of it keeps always changing.
If someone could tell me the precise name of that view or maybe (if you prefer it), send me a link to a tutorial to make it I'll be really thanked .
Any help is well received! Thanks! (And yes, as you can tell, I'm a noobie)

Comment: You could just decompile the app and see the type of the view probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the sliding images, that view is called View Pager.
Take a look at this implementation http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial